# How do make this regex lazy

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
XXXX:  150: some texxt: long text
```

I need to obtain only the digits between `::` like `:150:` in this case.

```
    echo "$LINE" |sed -n 's/^.*\XXXX:\(.*\)\:.*/\1/p'
```

gets me  `150:  some texxt`

How do I make it lazy and stop at the first match

Answer (score 0):

```
$ LINE='XXXX:  150: some texxt: long text'

$ echo "$LINE" | sed -r 's@^[^:]+:([^:]+):.*@\1@g'
 150
```

or

```
$ echo "$LINE" | perl -pe 's@.*?:([^:]+):.*@\1@g'
 150
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- `[^x]` means : exclude the **x** character

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work in your case, but this regex will find all numbers between : characters.

```
:\s*(\d+)\s*:
```

You will find the number in Capture Group 1.

Another similar approach where you don't need to look at capture groups and simply use the whole match would be (looks like this one doesn't work in Perl though):

```
(?<=:\s*)\d+(?=\s*:)
```

Answer (score 0):

The term is "non greedy":

```
^.*?\XXXX:\(.*\)\:.*
```

It is achieved by adding a `?` after `.*`

Comment: For his requirements I think you need to put the ? after the .* in the parentheses.

Comment: I thought greedy / lazy meaning to stop after it finds the first match.